# Index & Endnote in Eledmac

Tags: indexing, endnotes, eledmac

Could someone please check the attached MWE and explain why indexing is not printed and in the notes there are characters in uppercase but are useless in my application. It seems are reference to the notes of other groups.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\makeindex[title=Generale,columnsep=6pt,columnseprule]{}
\makeindex[name=esempio,title=Esempio,columns=2,columnsep=6pt,columnseprule]
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=100pt,    outer=154pt,top=100pt,bottom=50pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\linenummargin{inner}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,\ledsidenote{nota 1 nota 1 nota 1 nota 1 nota 1 nota 1}
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} habitant morbi tris
tique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.\ledrightnote{nota 2 nota 2 nota 2 nota 2 nota 2 nota 2 }
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
ultrices. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien
est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo
ultrices bibendum. \edtext{Aenean}{\Aendnote{Nota del gruppo A.}} faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pul
vinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci
eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam.
Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ul
tricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula
aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit
mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} a nulla. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridicu
lus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis.
Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volut
pat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus\footnote{et bibemus} viverra fermentum felis. Donec
nonummy pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} ante. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} adipiscing semper elit. Proin fer
mentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, mo
lestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan
nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend
consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} tincidunt pu
rus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec
bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi.
Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae
lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipisc
ing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue.
Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. \edtext{Aenean}{\Aendnote{Nota del gruppo A.}} placerat. Ut im
perdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar
elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.
Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
Fusce mauris. \edtext{Vestibulum}{\Bendnote{Nota del gruppo B.}} luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla
a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl.
Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque,\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis
lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in
sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu
lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo
lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula
sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla
egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat
lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.\edlabel{curcon}
Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet,
laoreet vitae, arcu. \edtext{Aenean}{\Aendnote{Nota del gruppo A.}} faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit,
rutrum at, molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit
amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque
vehicula, urna sed ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit
erat sed nulla. Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor odio, com
modo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy
in, fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio.
Sed commodo posuere pede. \edtext{Mauris}{\Dendnote{Nota del gruppo D.}} ut est. Ut quis purus. Sed ac odio.
Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio. Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan
risus eget odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque non elit.
Fusce sed justo eu urna porta tincidunt. Mauris felis odio, sollicitudin sed,
volutpat a, ornare ac, erat. Morbi quis dolor. Donec pellentesque,\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} erat ac
sagittis semper, nunc dui lobortis purus, quis congue purus metus ultricies
tellus. Proin et quam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Praesent sapien turpis, fermentum
vel, eleifend faucibus, vehicula eu, lacus.
Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Donec odio elit, dictum in, hendrerit sit amet,
egestas sed, leo. Praesent feugiat sapien aliquet odio. Integer vitae justo.
Aliquam vestibulum fringilla lorem. Sed neque lectus, consectetuer at, con
sectetuer sed, eleifend ac, lectus. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} eget lectus.
Proin eu metus. Sed porttitor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sus
pendisse eu lectus.\edlabel{susvf} Ut mi mi, lacinia sit amet, placerat et, mollis vitae, dui.
Sed ante tellus, tristique ut, iaculis eu, malesuada ac, dui. Mauris nibh leo,
facilisis non, adipiscing quis, ultrices a, dui.
Morbi luctus, wisi viverra faucibus pretium, nibh est placerat odio, nec
commodo wisi enim eget quam. Quisque libero justo, consectetuer a, feu
giat vitae, porttitor eu, libero. Suspendisse sed mauris vitae elit sollicitudin
malesuada. Maecenas ultricies eros sit amet ante. Ut venenatis velit. Mae
cenas sed mi eget dui varius euismod. Phasellus\edindex[esempio]{Phasellus} aliquet volutpat odio.
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cu
bilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet pede ac sem eleifend consectetuer. Nul
lam elementum, urna vel imperdiet sodales, elit ipsum pharetra ligula, ac
pretium ante \edtext{justo}{\Cendnote{Nota del gruppo C.}} a nulla. Curabitur tristique arcu eu metus. Vestibulum
lectus. Proin mauris. Proin eu nunc eu urna hendrerit faucibus. Aliquam
auctor, pede consequat laoreet varius, eros tellus scelerisque quam, pellen
tesque hendrerit ipsum dolor sed augue. Nulla nec lacus.\ledleftnote{nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 nota 3 }
Suspendisse vitae elit. Aliquam arcu neque, ornare in, ullamcorper quis,
commodo eu, libero. Fusce sagittis erat at erat tristique mollis. Maecenas
sapien libero, molestie et, lobortis in, sodales eget, dui. Morbi ultrices
rutrum lorem. Nam elementum ullamcorper leo. Morbi dui. Aliquam\ledleftnote{nota 4 nota 4 nota 4 nota 4 nota 4 nota 4 nota 4 nota 4 }
sagittis. Nunc placerat. Pellentesque\edindex[esempio]{Pellentesque} tristique sodales est. Maecenas im
perdiet lacinia velit. Cras non urna. Morbi eros pede, suscipit ac, varius
vel, egestas non, eros. Praesent malesuada, \edtext{diam}{\Eendnote{Nota del gruppo E.}} id pretium elementum,
eros sem dictum tortor, vel consectetuer odio sem sed wisi.

\pend
\endnumbering
\clearpage
\subsection{Note di livello A}\doendnotes{A}

\subsection{Note di livello B}\doendnotes{B}

\subsection{Note di livello C}\doendnotes{C}

\subsection{Note di livello D}\doendnotes{D}

\subsection{Note di livello E}\doendnotes{E}

\clearpage
Vedi \emph{Curabitur consectetuer.} a pagina \edpageref{curcon}, linea \lineref{curcon} e \emph{Suspendisse eu lectus.} a pagina \edpageref{susvf}, linea \lineref{susvf}.

\clearpage

\printindex
\printindex[esempio]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `example.ind` file is empty; I get an entry in the “Generale” index.

Comment: In a non eledmac file I have an index printout of the non-named index (Generale) and I supposed it was the same for the eledmac file. As suggested, I have changed the makeindex adding a name=gen and print index[gen] but I get "undefined index file".

Comment: I think you have to choose at least between `memoir` and `imakeidx`. If I don't use `imakeidx`, the indexing, at least, works fine. I suspect that `memoir` might also be responsible for the note oddities but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I normally use both memoir and imakeindex. The problem could be in eledmac but, agai, eledmac is compatible with memoir and imakeindex.

Comment: Indeed, eledmac is compatible with both memoir and imakeidx. However, there was a problem with edindex when using both memoir and imakeidx. Why ? Because eledmac has a specific edindex for memoir but when imakeidx is used, the memoir behavior change, and eledmac was not adapted.

Comment: But one other user report the problem. I have made a correction. I am waiting for his test. Maybe you could test for him/me? That should solve your problem.

Comment: To make the test, read the instruction here https://github.com/maieul/ledmac#debug to know how to download the branch "issue216". And make you report here or in https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/216. If you test is ok, I will start the releasing process.

Comment: for the other problem, I have to get a computer with tex to try it. But it should be better if you open one topic by ... topic/problem.

Comment: ok, thanks, I start with the edindex problem

Comment: for the endnotes problem, please try the branch "issue218". Notes that each problem is solved in a separate branch. When both problem will be solved, I will merge them to a release branch.

Comment: This is the first time I try to run a test and I do not want to make mistakes, so I'm sorry but I think it should be better if you run the test. Thanks.

Comment: no Paolo Mascetti, I need some one do the test, because as developper I can miss problem that user will see.

Comment: If really you can't do it, say it. But it will be better, to prevent sorting version with a new bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18195/discussion-between-paolo-mascetti-and-maieul).

Answer (score 1):

That was two bugs. The version 1.14.0, just uploaded in ctan, should solve them.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Tx

Comment: you're welcome. Please validate the answer, for other people.